# Authentication in cakePHP 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I cannot log in users in cakePHP 2.4, following the documentation I've created this. It says *successfully logged in* and also redirects to the destination URL (the users/loggedin action) but `$this->Auth->username` and `$this->Auth->password` stays blank, no sessions get created. It also gets redirected when trying to log in with wrong credentials. And also tells me the login was successful. I'm clueless now.

**AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => false),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'loggedin'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'loggedout'),
            'authError' => 'UNABLE TO LOG IN.'
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->allow('index','display','login','show_reg_form', 'view','signup');
    }

}
```

**UsersController.php**

I'll only paste the login function:

```
    public function login() {


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if($this->Auth->login(/*$this->request->data*/)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully logged in.')); 
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); 
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }

    }
```

**login.ctp**

The relevant part is:

```
<div class="container-login users form">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User');
                             echo $this->Form->input('username');
                             echo $this->Form->input('password');
                            echo $this->Form->end(__('Login',true));?>

                    </div>
```

Comment: `__('Login',true)` should be `__('Login')`. This is not cake1.3 anymore.

Comment: Are you passing parameters to $this->Auth->login? Or you just commented them here?

Comment: I'm not passing them, because when I last uncommented that part, I could login with anything. I read in the documentation, it should work without the arguments specified.

Comment: So using the parameters you mentioned, it creates a session for a non-existing user, too.

Comment: I never mentioned that you should use parameters. Actually you only use parameters if you manually do the login.

Comment: Try moving the $this->Auth->allow(...) in UsersController beforeFilter and remove the AppController beforeFilter with all its contents.

Comment: Or just comment the first 2 lines in beforeFilter in AppController..

Comment: Tried it, does not make difference. :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logged in user details should be read like this:

```
$id          = $this->Auth->user('id');
$username    = $this->Auth->user('username');
...
$other_field = $this->Auth->user('other_field');
```

The is no field username in the Auth Object.

You can't read the password field from Auth using **user** method.

You will need to query the user from the database if you want to get the password. But you should leave the password hashed and alone.

Edit:
Since you can access the 'loggedin' page this means that there is a user session created. You just need to change the way you access the user data.

Edit2:
Specify the authentication handlers by adding following line to your Auth:

```
'Auth' => array(
    ....
    'authenticate' => array('Form') 
)
```

Edit3:
Check again that the database field storing the password is VARCHAR with 40 length.

Comment: Here's the catch. It also gets redirected when trying to log in with wrong credentials. And also tells me the login was successful.

Comment: And I should have guessed that?